# Despliegue de aplicación Spring-Boot en weblogic

Tags: spring, angular, maven, weblogic

estoy construyendo un proyecto con Angular6 y Spring, ya hice todo el proyecto en mi equipo y funciona de maravilla, sin embargo ahora debo desplegar el proyecto en un servidor WebLogic, genero el war de spring con maven, sin embargo al desplegarlo en WebLogic, me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Al instalar el war en el WebLogic]

Mi método main, es el siguiente, y en mi máquina se despliega perfectamente con un servidor tomcat.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //SpringApplication.run(ParameterApplication.class, args);

    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ParameterApplication.class);
    builder.headless(false).run(args);
}
```

A continuación el log, generado por el servidor:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule.<init>(JavaTimeModule.java:168)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:124)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:743)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:624)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:608)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59)
at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.java:29)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.httpPutFormContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:163)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$254f370c.CGLIB$httpPutFormContentFilter$0(<generated>:0)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$254f370c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2692fcf3.invoke(<generated>:0)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$254f370c.httpPutFormContentFilter(<generated>:0)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:182)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:177)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:159)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:81)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1421)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1360)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1341)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1907)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1849)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
```

> 

Comment: Creo que seria bueno que compartieras un poco mas de detalles de los logs por que con lo que hay no creo que se pueda identificar el posible problema.

Comment: No sé, qué pueda estar causando este error, la aplicación ya está construida y no he podido desplegarla en weblogic. Agradezco tu atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por favor, ¿podrías poner qué dice el servidor weblogic donde estás desplegando la aplicación? A ser posible, los códigos BEA-xxxxx o los errores que encuentres en dicho log. Vendrán etiquetados como Warning o Error más Deployer o algo similar.

Comprueba de paso que no tienes ningún error nada más arrancar el servidor donde está desplegada tu aplicación.

También estaría bien que te aseguraras de si la versión que tienes instalada en local es la misma que tienes instalado en el servidor que estas desplegando, con el mismo nivel de parche.

Asegurate que weblogic levanta con la versión de java correspondiente a la que tienes en local.

Asegurate que los ficheros que has subido a tu aplicación y que actualizas, tienen los permisos adecuados de lectura y escritura si es linux. Si es windows, asegurate que el propietario de esos archivos es weblogic.

No actualices los despliegues. Despliega desde cero con las modificaciones que hayas implementado. Para descartar que sea un problema con la actualización de las aplicaciones.

Cuentanos los resultados.

Un saludo.

Comment: Manu, de hecho el error generado al desplegar el war dentro del weblogic, logré solucionarlo.

Era un error generado por el formateo de la fecha que se envía desde el angular. Además añadí una ruta al weblogic.xml, llamando esos paquetes, lo cual funcionó para ese error, sin embargo me encuentro en otro error, generado por oracle al desplegar la app.

Soy nuevo en el foro, no sé si deba crear otra pregunta, o actualizar ésta para poder obtener solución, qué me recomiendas?

Comment: Validé permisos y versiones, todo se encuentra en regla. Sin embargo, no sé qué configuración deba tener el dispatcher-servlet.xml, y es quién creo que debe generar el error.

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este error, agregué la librería que se solicitaba al weblogic.xml.
El cual quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<wls:context-root>/myweb</wls:context-root>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.oracle</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Además fue necesario revisar que los parámetros de envío y de recepción sean los mismos, ya que en angular enviaba el parámetro fecha de tipo string, y en Java está declarado de tipo Date(), lo cual invalidaba la conversión.